# data retention in stm32

Tags: stm32, flash-memory

Presented data retention for STM32f103c8 in its datasheet is: "1 kcycle at T = 105c: 10 years".

Can anyone explain this to me?

1- What is 1 kcycle? is it 1000 cycle (why "k" is not in capital?

2- What is a cycle? is it Write/Erase per minutes?

3- Does this sentence mean that I can use it at 105 degrees of Celsius for 10 years while I write and erase data 1000 times in each minute?

I'm putting the datasheet as a reference below.

[image]

Comment: This question would have been a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k for kilo- (meaning 1000) is always always lower case, whatever the case of what surrounds it.  Eg: km = kilometre; kPa = kilopascal.

How I understand the datasheet is this:

The maximum number of times that you should erase and write this part is 10000 times.

If you erase and write the part 1000 times (1000 erases, 1000 writes) and then keep it at 85 degrees, the contents will be preserved for at least 30 years.

If you erase and write the part 1000 times (1000 erases, 1000 writes) and then keep it at 105 degrees, the contents will be preserved for at least 10 years.

If you erase and write the part 10000 times (10000 erases, 10000 writes) and then keep it at 55 degrees, the contents will be preserved for at least 20 years.

All this data is obviously predicted.  The process that these parts are made by has not been around for 30 yours for them to know this for certain.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. It is the first time that I'm focusing on this particular limitation so it was a bit weird for me. Isn't it a bit low? I can use the flash memory just 10000 times? After that, it will be unusable?

Comment: After that it is not *guaranteed* to be usable.  (If this solves your question can you please accept the answer with the tick mark on the left?)